# SQL not showing just one product instead of more

Tags: mysql, sql

```
            $query_sub = "SELECT * FROM `product_mappings` LEFT JOIN `product_list` ON `product_mappings`.ID_PRODUCT =`product_list`.ID  WHERE ID_USER='" . $row{'ID'} . "'";
            $result_sub = mysql_query($query_sub);
            if ($result_sub && mysql_num_rows($result_sub) > 0)
            {
                $data_products = array();
                while ($row_sub = mysql_fetch_array($result_sub))
                {
                    $data_sub = array();
                    $data_sub["ID"] = $row_sub{'ID'};
                    $data_sub["product"] = $row_sub{'PRODUCT'};


                            $query_sub_unactive = "SELECT * FROM `product_list` WHERE ID != '" . $row_sub{'ID'} . "' ";
                                                $result_sub_unactive = mysql_query($query_sub_unactive);
                                                if ($result_sub_unactive && mysql_num_rows($result_sub_unactive) > 0)
                                                {
                                                    $data_products_unactive = array();
                                                    while ($row_sub_unactive = mysql_fetch_array($result_sub_unactive))
                                                    {
                                                        $data_sub_unactive = array();
                                                        $data_sub_unactive["ID"] = $row_sub_unactive{'ID'};
                                                        $data_sub_unactive["productss"] = $row_sub_unactive{'PRODUCT'};


                                                        array_push($data_products_unactive, $data_sub_unactive);

                                                    }
                                                    $data_current["productsUnactive"] = $data_products_unactive;
                                                }


                    array_push($data_products, $data_sub);


                }

                $data_current["products"] = $data_products;
```

Hi guys ! This is query where I should select only products that are not already in main query. I am checking if ID is the same as you can see. For example I load 4 products (of 15) with main query and unactive should load 11 of items in this case.. but loads 14 items.. so it "removes" just one product from list. Any clue?

Thanks !

Comment: I would find your question much easier to digest if you just had the SQL queries in a separate section, rather than garbled with the PHP code.

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I don't know what you mean. I am quite new into php, SQL and that stuff.

Comment: Funny... I've been coding PHP for something like 15 years and I have just learnt that you can actually access arrays items with [both square brackets and curly braces](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-104).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `product_list` WHERE ID != '" . $row_sub{'ID'} . "' ";
```

This query is checking 1 ID at a time and is always going to return the other 14 rows. What you need is a "NOT IN" query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_list` WHERE ID NOT IN ("id1","id2","id3","id4");
```

Comment: This would do its job if I would always want to return same IDs. Problem is that IDs can change (if you change which programs you would want to have active and which not).

Comment: @JMusic: What Mohamed is saying is that it makes no sense to look for missing products with just one ID, because the main query gets you several IDs. Hence you cannot retrieve the missing products in the loop giving it just one ID. It has to be done outside the loop for all IDs at once.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand yes. Will take care of it with angular then. Thank you !

Comment: Yes @ThorstenKettner is right. I could have been clearer.